# Dynamic og:image angular2

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph

We want to share an url pointing to an Angular 2 on social networks. For example Facebook and Skype.

on our website, at this url is displayed a dynamic picture depending on the actual URL parameters and query strings we set.

For example, going to `http://oursite.com/#/show/5448sd84f8d4sf8` will display `/images/5448sd84f8d4sf8.png`.

By sharing a link, it seems both Facebook and Skype use Open Graph meta `og:image` to display a thumbnail or snapshot of the website:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.png">
```

Is there a way to set a dynamic og:image depending on the url, as explain below: linking our url would show

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://oursite.com/images/5448sd84f8d4sf8.png">
```

**And then how to make sure Facebook and Skype for example to actually parse the dynamic image?**

Comment: Since 4.0.0-beta.0 was introduced Meta service https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/72361fb

Comment: The fact is, by using the meta or ng2-metadata, the og:image is generated during JS eval. But for example Skype by pasting a link doesn't crawl using JS. So no image is showing.

Comment: here is the reason and a solution I posted before...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43430982/3103979

Answer (score 4):

You can use Angular's `Meta` service to modify the meta tags:

```js
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class MyClass {
  constructor(
    private metaService: Meta
  ) {
    // Build and change the og:image meta
    const baseUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;
    const imageUrl = baseUrl + '/path/to/image.png';

    this.metaService.addTag( { property: 'og:image', content: imageUrl } );
    // or it it already exists, use this 'updateTag'
    // this.metaService.updateTag( { property: 'og:image', content: imageUrl } );
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is, until javascript is loaded, the original og:image on the html page will remain unchanged, and so the Facebook, Skype or whatever crawler won't see it.

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy what if I try ```<meta property="og:image" content="mysite.com/generate_image">```, think server can give different images? no?

Answer (score 2):

I also got this same issue.
 Angular 2 browser application is running on client side. to fix this issue we need handle this form server side, when the request came from the client. (simple update response with og meta tags)

there are several options:

- go for Angular Universal : bit difficult approach
- simple handle this through URL rewriting (web server) : this what I used

this is my web config for url rewrite : I took dynamic og image name from query parameter (..og=[filename])

```html
  <rewrite>  
 <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
 <rule name="Add tracking script" preCondition="" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
   <match filterByTags="None" pattern="ogimagepath" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="[^]*og=([0-9]+)" />
  </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:1}" />
  </rule>
</outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use ng2-metadata, it's easy to implement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-metadata

Comment: Link is not an answer. You should add some usage example.

Comment: Currently ng2-metadata is not working in combination with crawler except google.

Comment: As a addendum. here is the link mentioning only google is parsing js.
https://github.com/fulls1z3/ng2-metadata/issues/4