# Angular15 Dynamic Og Image Rewrite using nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

We have a ecommerce web application developed in Angular15 and deployed on an NGINX server. We need to serve dynamic og:image tag (in index.html file) since users will be able to share products listed on the platform with social applications (facebook, whatsapp).

One solution we found was to change the app into Server Side Rendering using Angular Universal. However the sheer complexity of the app as it stands now has made it very difficult to convert to an SSR. We found another solutions in stackoverflow ([Dynamic og:image angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454978/dynamic-ogimage-angular2)) which speaks about URL rewriting to capture the image tag from the url and write it into the index.html file.
Considering we have the URL as

https://website.com/products/abcd?image=product_image.jpg

What is the best way to achieve this using NGINX.